# How to delete created element via JQUERY?

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

```
        $(function(){
            var namecounter = 0
            $("#getitem").click(function(){
                namecounter++
                var txtval = $("#txt").val();
                $('<tr><td><input type="button" name="txt'+ namecounter +'" value="remove" /><input type="text" id="txt'+ namecounter +'a" name="txt'+ namecounter +'a" value="'+txtval+'"/></td><td></td><td></td></tr>').appendTo('#pasok');
            });
            $(":button[name^='txt']").click(function(){
                var currentValue = $(this);
                var target = $("#" + currentValue.attr("id") + "a");
                $(target).remove();
            });
        });
```

How to delete created element via JQUERY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button doesn't have an `id` attribute, it has a `name` attribute (both of which are also a directly accessible DOM properties), so you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    var namecounter = 0
    $("#getitem").click(function(){
        namecounter++
        var txtval = $("#txt").val();
        $('<tr><td><input type="button" name="txt'+ namecounter +'" value="remove" /><input type="text" id="txt'+ namecounter +'a" name="txt'+ namecounter +'a" value="'+txtval+'"/></td><td></td><td></td></tr>').appendTo('#pasok');
    });
    $("#pasok").delegate(":button[name^='txt']", "click", function(){
        $("#" + this.name + "a").remove();
    });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/aBCd6/).

Also note the use of [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) so it works on the buttons you're adding, not just the ones that were there when your `document.ready` function ran.

Comment: You probably need a space before the `a` though. `"a"` → `" a"`

Answer (score 1):

your target variable is already a jquery object. So you should change `$(target).remove();` to `target.remove();`

Comment: That’s a good optimization, but sadly that can’t be the reason why his code breaks. Stuff like `$($($($($('body')))))` still works; it’s just REALLY bad for performance.